# UITableViewController with 2 cell per row

Tags: xcode, image, ios5, uitableview, cell

I wanted to create a custom UITableViewCell with the following design. I wanted to show two pictures per row, an each picture has a tittle and a short description. I dont want to have the two pictures in the same cell, they have to have different content. When you click on one image, it has to open the description.

I am working in ios 5, do you have any idea or any sample code

Comment: For a UITableView, a row and a cell are really the same thing.  (You can have two images in one cell and detect which one is tapped.)

Comment: Try the following sample code.It will help you a lot. It has two "cell" per row, in each cell it has a `UIImageView`.I think that it will solve your problem. [GridView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gmgridview)